# Calculating the moving average of rows of a dataframe, 12 columns at a time, starting from the left most point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as such

```
    A   B   C   D  

X   1   2   3   4

Y   5   6   7   8

Z   9   10  11  12
```

I need to perform a moving average on a row basis. Here is an example resultant df with a moving average 2 columns at  a time:

```
     A    B    C     D  

X   1.5  2.5  3.5    4

Y   5.5  6.5  7.5    8

Z   9.5  10.5 11.5  12
```

Notice that the last column doesn't have any proceeding values so it just remains the original value. In my case, I would like a 12 column moving average until 12 is no longer possible, then to decrement to 11, 10, 9, ect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need reverse the order of column then do `rolling`

```
df=df.T.iloc[::-1].rolling(2,min_periods=1).mean().iloc[::-1].T
Out[348]: 
     A     B     C     D
X  1.5   2.5   3.5   4.0
Y  5.5   6.5   7.5   8.0
Z  9.5  10.5  11.5  12.0
```